# SDL Help. Xcode. Build and Run Error

Tags: xcode, frameworks, warnings, sdl

I have been going off of this tutorial
http://www.noquarterarcade.com/xcode-sdl-development-setup

So, I have downloaded both the SDL Runtime Library and the SDL Development Library and put their content in the specified folders. I have made sure that have followed these steps correctly.

However, when I click build and run I get an error and 2 warning.

```
Error:
1) Command/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Warnings:
1) Directory'/Users/RustyShackleford/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

it says this warning twice

Here is my buildlog:

```
Build Try of project Try with configuration Debug

Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try normal x86_64
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
ld: framework not found SDL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try normal i386
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.4
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

what are your thought?

Answer (score 0):

OK, what I see here is that you have a different User name.  Your buidlog references the user nickcarver while your warning references RustyShackleford.  Could it be that you are pointing to the wrong library folder?  If not, does the user you are running under have access to the other user's library (doubtful)?

If this isn't the cause of the error, you will need to dig further.  In xcode, right click the error line and choose "Open These Latest Results as Transcript Text File".  This should give you the true error log.  Search in there for your error number and post the error information.

Comment: I have added an edited version of my question which should have all the information you need

thanks!

Comment: @Rusty - The error says basically that the SDL library is not found.  Since you are also getting the two warnings that say the path isn't found, I would say that the issue must be in where you put the files.  Have you manually verified that these paths exist?

Comment: Yes. I have the SDL.framework folder inside of Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks

I don't understand why it cant find it!

Comment: I am such a noob. The problem was this. I was using the MacintoshHD/Library/Frameworks  rather than nickcarver/Library/Frameworks

I thought this was the right place to put it because it had all of the other frameworks in it. Problem solved.

Thanks you