# SDL and Xcode. Build and Run Error

Tags: xcode, warnings, sdl

I have been going off of this tutorial http://www.noquarterarcade.com/xcode-sdl-development-setup

So, I have downloaded both the SDL Runtime Library and the SDL Development Library and put their content in the specified folders. I have made sure that have followed these steps correctly.

However, when I click build and run I get an error and 2 warning.

**Error:**
1) Command/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Build Try of project Try with configuration Debug

```
Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try normal x86_64
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
ld: framework not found SDL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try normal i386
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.4
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

**Warnings:**
1) Directory'/Users/RustyShackleford/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found

it says this warning twice

Build Try of project Try with configuration Debug

```
Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try normal x86_64
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
ld: framework not found SDL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Ld build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try normal i386
cd "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.4
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk "-L/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" "-F/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Debug" -F/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks -filelist "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o "/Users/nickcarver/Desktop/Lazy Foo Tutorials/Try/build/Try.build/Debug/Try.build/Objects-normal/i386/Try"

ld: warning: directory '/Users/nickcarver/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

How do I do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDL Help. Xcode. Build and Run Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918932/sdl-help-xcode-build-and-run-error)

Comment: I did post this same question yesterday, but it did not have the information about Errors and Warnings that were necessary.

Im still looking for some help tho..

Comment: In that case, the expected behaviour is to edit the original question and make it clear that you’ve updated it with more information. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, carefully check for dublicates.
Also, try changing the foundation template.